# Update status bar text when a button in another WPF window is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have two windows: `Window A` and `Window B`. When `Window A` is opened, `Window B` will be opened as well. In both windows, I have two similar buttons: `Button A` and `Button B`. Both buttons carry same function, so for convenience, I assign `Button A`'s function point to `Button B`'s function.

In Window A:

```
WindowA windowA;

    public WindowA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        windowA = new WindowA();
        windowA.Show();    
    }       


    private void BtnA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        windowB.BtnB_Click(sender, e);
    }
```

In Button B:

```
    public void BtnB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Actions that will be carried out
    }
```

When `Button B` is pressed, the text on the `status bar` in `Window B` will change (`txtStatusBarB.Text = "Some Text"`). So, my problem is how can I update the text (same text) on the `status bar` in Window A as well when either `Button A` or `Button B` is pressed?

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to call `new WindowA` in the constructor of WindowA?

Answer (score 1):

Store reference to WindowA in WindowB. This reference can be passed in WinB's constructor. Then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi @AnjumSKhan, thanks for your reply. Can you give me some example on this?

Comment: WindowA wA = new WindowA(); WindowB wB = new WindowB(wA); wARef = wA. wARef.txtStatusBarA.Text = "Some Text" .

Comment: @YWah, In that case, is it possible to use MVVM, same view model for both windows ?